# Google spreadsheets changing values

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I'd want to change numerical values in my spreadsheet on 1 column only. 1 should become 5, 2 should become 4, 3 stays 3, 4 should become 2 and 5 should become 1. Is it possible in any way?
Then I need to sum those values for start. I wrote the summation formula, but it also doesn't work as it should.

```
=IF(LOOKUP(5, B2:B7), SUM(B2:B7)-4*COUNTIF(B2:B7, 5), IF(LOOKUP(4, B2:B7), SUM(B2:B7)-2*COUNTIF(B2:B7, 4), IF(LOOKUP(2, B2:B7), SUM(B2:B7)+2*COUNTIF(B2:B7, 2), IF(LOOKUP(1, B2:B7), SUM(B2:B7)+4*COUNTIF(B2:B7, 1), SUM(B2:B7)))))
```

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: Are these single digits? Or if you have `123`, do you want to change that to `543`?

Comment: Those are single digits, yes. I can upload photos of the idea here.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with "Find and Replace". I first replaced all 1 and 2 with *1 and *2 and then all 5 with 1 and all 4 with 2 and then *1 with 5 and *2 with 4.